# liferay login without portlet

Tags: java, liferay

How can I log in user from page header without making my own login portlet and without redirecting to login page (maybe via javascript or something else)? I have two input fields in header - for username and password and I dont't want extra login page.

Comment: Liferay already has the notion of cross-portlet authentication baked in. Does this not work for your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Liferay's 7cogs theme

```
<form action="/web/guest/home" method="post" name="loginadmin">
    <input name="p_p_id" type="hidden" value="58">
    <input name="p_p_lifecycle" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input name="p_p_mode" type="hidden" value="view">
    <input name="p_p_state" type="hidden" value="maximized">
    <input name="_58_struts_action" type="hidden" value="/login/login">
    <input name="_58_login" type="hidden" value="bruno@7cogs.com">
    <input name="_58_password" type="hidden" value="bruno">
    ...
    <a class="express_login" href="#" onclick="document.loginadmin.submit();return false;">Login as Bruno.</a>
    ...
</form>
```

So either use this form, in your header, but instead of having hidden fields for "_58_login" and "_58_password" use text/password inputs (that you already have, but change names to be "_58_login" and "_58_password"), or populate those hidden fields with values from your header fields with javascript and submit this (shown above) form.

Testing this (Liferay 6.1) I had to modify, to make it work, form action to be

```
<form action="/en_GB/web/guest/home" method="post" name="loginadmin">
```

Notice the added locale (/en_GB). In your case probably is different but change it with your value.

Comment: Thank you! I made login in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can write autologin-hook that read from header:

http://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/auto-login